# Apply current layout to another network with same nodes but different edges

Tags: neural-network, gephi

I was wondering if there is a way to apply positions of nodes to another networks. Both network share the same node, but have different edges.

Can you do this in Gephi? I noticed that GeoLayout can fix the geographic position, but is there a way to obtain the on screen ordination of all nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Gephi 0.8.2 there is this plugin that is called `Data laboratory helper`. This will help you, once you have laid out your graph, to retrieve the x and y coordinates of the layout, by choosing `Get standart column` (sic).

[image]

Thereafter, you choose `X-coordinate(Node table)` and resp. `Y-coordinate(Node table)` and brings you the x and y coordinates as a column in the node table. You can also set the coordinates that way if you already have a column containing coordinates, as floats or doubles.

***This is not yet implemented in Gephi 0.9 though.***